# Android How to hide and display items in a ListView when a ListView item is clicked

Tags: android, android-listview

Hey i'm using and android ListView I want to display some items while adding others in the same ListView when i click on a ListView item. what i mean is when i click on one item some images are displayed on the same row. when i click on another item the previous images disappear while I'm left with the ones in the new row please help here is my code

```
inventoryList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    inventoryList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
            LinearLayout lButtons;

            // Hides all items in the listView adapter  
            for (int i = 0; i < inventoryList.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {


                   View v1 = inventoryList.getChildAt(i);  
                   lButtons = (LinearLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.layout_update_buttons);
                   lButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            }

            //Display images of currently clicked item
            lButtons = (LinearLayout) arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_update_buttons);
            lButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    });
```

it currently gives me a java.lang.nullPointerException in this particular line

```
lButtons = (LinearLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.layout_update_buttons);
```

Comment: did you check if v1 is null?

Comment: dude thanks for your help I'll post the answer here and accept it you've really helped me @OnurA.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I got after some help

```
inventoryList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    inventoryList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
            LinearLayout lButtons;

            // Hides all items in the listView adapter  
            for (int i = 0; i < inventoryList.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {


                   View v1 = inventoryList.getChildAt(i);  
                   if(v1 != null){
                   lButtons = (LinearLayout) v1.findViewById(R.id.layout_update_buttons);
                   lButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   }


            }

            //Display images of currently clicked item
            lButtons = (LinearLayout) arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_update_buttons);
            lButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    });
```

Comment: adding a a null check is not a solution . Before posting all this kind of question please go thoroughly through your code , try to debug it and only if after that you doesn't get a solution then only post. It will save both your's and our's time. Dont do like this that you get an exception and started posting in SOF.